# Is it Possible to Use the the Github Plugin with Gerrit 2.10 Behind a Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache, github, reverse-proxy, gerrit

I have a gerrit instance running. I have the github plugin built. But what I want to know is, does gerrit 2.10 support the GitHub plugin while running gerrit behind a reverse proxy? If so what authentication method do I use?

Right now my gerrit.conf looks like:

```
[gerrit]
    basePath = /home/gerrit2/Repos/Projects
    canonicalWebUrl = http://www.matthewh.me/gerrit/
[database]
    type = mysql
    hostname = localhost
    database = reviewdb
    username = gerrit2
[index]
    type = LUCENE
[auth]
    type = OPENID_SSO
    openIdDomain = @matthewh.me
    openIdSsoUrl = https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
[sendemail]
    smtpServer = smtp.gmail.com
    smtpServerPort = 465
    smtpEncryption = SSL
    sslVerify = false
    smtpUser = matthew.hoggan@matthewh.me
    smtpPass = <my password>
[container]
    user = gerrit2
    javaHome = /home/gerrit2/Devel/jdk1.7.0_60/jre
[sshd]
    listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
    listenUrl = proxy-http://www.matthewh.me:8081/gerrit/
[cache]
    directory = cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's Possible ,

**(pre-compiled) we going to install them**

github 2.10-SNAPSHOT ([github-oauth](http://ci.gerritforge.com/view/Plugins-stable-2.10/job/Plugin_github_stable-2.10/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/github-oauth/target/github-oauth-2.10-SNAPSHOT.jar) && [github-plugin](http://ci.gerritforge.com/view/Plugins-stable-2.10/job/Plugin_github_stable-2.10/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/github-plugin/target/github-plugin-2.10-SNAPSHOT.jar))

> Download (github-oauth*.jar, the GitHub OAuth library for
>   authenticating Gerrit users) Install the GitHub OAuth filter into the
>   Gerrit libraries (/lib under the Gerrit site directory)

The GitHub OAuth JAR file needs to copied to the Gerrit /lib directory; this is required to allow Gerrit to use it for filtering all HTTP requests and enforcing the GitHub three-step authentication process:

Download (github-plugin*.jar, the Gerrit plugin for integrating with GitHub repositories and pull requests)
Install the GitHub Plugin into the Gerrit plugins (/plugins under the Gerrit site directory)

> The GitHub plugin includes the additional support for the overall
>   configuration, the advanced GitHub repositories replication, and the
>   integration of pull requests into the Code Review process.

**Register Gerrit as a GitHub OAuth application ([source](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/using-gerrit-github))**

Before going through the Gerrit init, we need to tell GitHub to trust Gerrit as a partner application. This is done through the generation of a ClientId/ClientSecret pair associated to the exact Gerrit URLs that will be used for initiating the 3-step OAuth authentication.

We can register a new application in GitHub through the URL https://github.com/settings/applications/new, where the following three fields are requested:

1. Application name : It is the logical name of the application
   authorized to access GitHub, for example, Gerrit.
2. Main URL : The Gerrit canonical web URL used for redirecting to GitHub OAuth authentication, for example, https://mydomain.com:8443.
3. Callback URL : The URL that GitHub should redirect to when the OAuth
       authentication is successfully completed, for example,
       https://mydomain.com:8443/#/.

**You can check full tutorial on my blog**

http://codexc.com/blog/2014/09/how-to-installation-and-configuration-gerrit-v2-10-with-github-oauth/

**(put in etc/gerrit.config)**

```
[auth]
    type = HTTP
    httpHeader = GITHUB_USER
    httpDisplayNameHeader = GITHUB_NAME
    httpEmailHeader = GITHUB_EMAIL
    loginUrl = /login
    loginText = GitHub Sign-in
    registerPageUrl = /plugins/github-plugin/static/account.html
    gitBasicAuth = true
```